# Is this a Enoki aka. velvet shank aka. Flammulina velutipes?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

In December in southern Germany I found the following mushroom on a some remains of a tree. From what I read, saw and felt (sticky cap when wet), I am very sure it is a velvet shank, especially because in winter there are not many other types of mushrooms around to be confused with. However I would like to know if someone can confirm/debunk my assumption?

[image: habitat]
[image: detail]

Comment: Please don't rely on any identification help given here to decide whether you should eat a mushroom you found.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree with your identification of *Flammulina velutipes* based on the description in *Mushrooms Demystified* (David Arora, 1986) and the [page on *MushroomExpert.Com*](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/flammulina_velutipes.html) (Michael Kuo, 2013). Arora emphasizes the viscid yellow-orange to brownish cap, velvety dark-brown stalk, lack of a veil, white spores, and growth habit as diagnostic characteristics. Take a spore print and note the texture of the stem next time you come across them as additional tests. If the substrate is not too decomposed, also note if it is growing on a hardwood or softwood (*F. velutipes* only grows on hardwoods).

[image: sample image]
<sup>Fig. 1. *Flammulina velutipes*. source: [MushroomExpert](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/flammulina_velutipes.html)</sup>

I'm not familiar with European mushrooms, so I don't know if there are look-alikes where you are, but this mushroom does grow in Germany (see map at [*MushroomExpert*](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/flammulina_velutipes.html)).

And of course, heed Bryan Krause's advice.